# Adding object values to the correct SharePoint list columns---getting blank SharePoint rows

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, excel

I'm parsing an Excel file and it's coming back as an array object. I want to add each object value into the correct SharePoint list column.

I'm using POST to upload to info and the data is going through. SharePoint recognizes that two items (the two rows from the test.xlsx file) have been uploaded, but when I refresh the SP list both items are blank.

[image]

It looks as if each array object is getting added to the column, but it's getting rejected by SharePoint (having too many values, or something). Any thoughts? How can I make sure that the Holiday Title goes in the `Holidays` column, the Holiday Location goes in the `Location` column, etc.?

---

JS:

```
 reader.onload = function(e) { 
    let data = e.target.result;
    let workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });

    workbook.SheetNames.forEach((sheetName) => {
        let XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);

        console.log("xl: ", XL_row_object) // You can see this at the bottom of the post

        if (XL_row_object) { 
            $.each(XL_row_object, function(value) {
                // this.value = $(value)

                let getTitle = XL_row_object.map(x => x.Title)
                let getOffice = XL_row_object.map(x => x.Office)
                let getStartTime = XL_row_object.map(x => x["Start Time"])
                let getEndTime = XL_row_object.map(x => x["End Time"])

                addItemToSPList(getTitle, getOffice, getStartTime, getEndTime)
            })

        } else {
            console.log('Parsed JSON does not appear to have necessary values')
        }

    })

} // reader.onload

// some other code 

}

function addItemToSPList(value) {
    let holidaysColumns = {
        "__metadata":{"type": "SP.Data.holidaysListItem"},
        "Title": value.getTitle,
        "Location": value.office, // did this instead of getOffice to see if anything changed
// FYI, the column in SP is "Location"
        "Start Time": value.getStartTime,
        "End Time": value.getEndTime
    };

    let listName = "holidays";
    return fetch(
// etc
```

---

Console snippet:

```
xl:(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {Title: "Festivus", Office: "London", Start Time: 43895, End Time: 43895, __rowNum__: 1}
1: {Title: "Founder's Week", Office: "London", Start Time: 43897, End Time: 43900, __rowNum__: 2}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using your code like:

```
function addItemToSPList(getTitle, getOffice, getStartTime, getEndTime) {
    let holidaysColumns = {
        "__metadata": {"type": "SP.Data.holidaysListItem"},
        "Title": getTitle,
        "Location": getOffice, // FYI, the column in SP is "Location"
        "Start Time": getStartTime,
        "End Time": getEndTime
    };

    let listName = "holidays";
    return fetch(
// etc
```

Comment: Hi @Bodrov, does this answers your question? have you got it working or you still facing this issue?